# Where is the constant for the new FirebaseAppInvite API

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-invites

`AppInvite.API` is deprecated. I can't find the new constant in documentation.

Using Firebase version 11.0.2

Answer (score 0):

The Invites API has [changed in 11.0.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) to closer match the other Firebase APIs.  [Follow the new instructions instead.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android)

Comment: I follow it. And the guide in Android studio is still to be updated